# Firebase has not been correctly initialized Flutter for WEB ONLY

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

In new fresh project, cannot connect to Firestore.
Created Firestore project and added this code to index.html last inside body tag

```
<script type="module">
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-analytics.js";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxxx-xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
  appId: "x:xxxxxxx:web:xxxxxxxxxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

In pubspec.yaml added cloud_firestore dependency
In flutter code

```
 StreamBuilder(
            stream:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('xxxx').snapshots(),
 ...
```

Get **Firebase has not been correctly initialized** error